# Redux: Props undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

Redux: Undefined Prop

[Undefined Prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDEYm.png)
I want to pass down a prop from my container component, down to my presentational component via props, but I haven't been able to do so without the prop being **undefined**. Why isn't the **number** prop being passed down to the presentational component?

Creating the store with the initial stae and rootreducer:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
...
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

const initialState = {
    multiply: 2,
    number: 1
}

export const store = createStore(
    ...initialState, 
    rootReducer, 
    applyMiddleware(logger(), thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension()
);
```

Reducer for multiply actions and divide actions:

```
const multiplyReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'MULTIPLY':
            return state = {
                ...state,
                number: state.number * action.payload
            }
        case 'DIVIDE':
            return state = {
                ...state,
                number: state.number / action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default multiplyReducer;
```

Root reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import multiplyReducer from './multiplyReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  multiply: multiplyReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Wrapping the app in a Provider:

```
import Multiplier from './ContainerComponents/Multiplier';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = ({ store }) => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Multiplier}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Actions:

```
export const multiplyAction = {
    type: 'MULTIPLY',
    payload: 2
}

export const divideAction = {
    type: 'DIVIDE',
    payload: 2
}
```

Container Component:

```
    import MultiplierDisplay from '../StyleComponents/MultiplierDisplay';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {multiplyAction, divideAction} from '../Redux/actions/multiplyActions';

    class Multiplier extends React.Component {

        render() {

            return (<MultiplierDisplay {...this.props} />)
        }
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {multiply: state.multiply, number: state.number}
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            handleClick: (event) => {
                dispatch(multiplyAction)
            },
            handleClick2: (event) => {
                dispatch(divideAction)
            }
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Multiplier);
```

Presentational Component:

```
const MultiplierDisplay = (props) => {

        return (
            <div
                className="top"
                style={{
                alignContent: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
                <div className="App">
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
                        <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <h1 style={{
                    marginLeft: 20
                }}>
                    Multiply the count:
                </h1>
                <p style={{
                    fontSize: '3em'
                }}>
                    Count: {props.number}
                </p>
                <button
                    style={{
                    marginLeft: 100,
                    width: '20%',
                    height: '20%'
                }}
                    onClick={props.handleClick}
                    title="Multiply">
                    Multiply
                </button>
                <button
                    style={{
                    marginLeft: 50,
                    width: '20%',
                    height: '20%'
                }}
                    onClick={props.handleClick2}
                    title="Divide">
                    Divide
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default MultiplierDisplay;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prop number isn't passed on to the presentation component being you haven't passed it down from the container,

```
class Multiplier extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (<MultiplierDisplay/>)   // this is where you are not passing it down
    }
};
```

If you need to pass all the props down to the MultiplierDisplay component you can write

```
class Multiplier extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (<MultiplierDisplay {...this.props}/>)
    }
};
```

or if you want to pass selected props down, you can write them like

class Multiplier extends React.Component {

```
    render() {
        const { multiply, number, handleClick, handleClick2 } = this.props;
        return (<MultiplierDisplay multiply={multiply} number={number} handleClick={handleClick} handleClick2={handleClick2}/>)
    }
};
```

Also you need to get the state from `state.multiple` you are having number and multiply in `multiplierReducer` which you are using as `multiply`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {multiply: state.multiply.multiply, number: state.multiply.number}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleClick: (event) => {
            dispatch(multiplyAction)
        },
        handleClick2: (event) => {
            dispatch(divideAction)
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Multiplier);
```

Comment: The value for number is still undefined, despite adding it as a prop to </MultiplierDisplay>, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @KaceyOkafor, yes you have used combineReducer, but you are not incorporating it while getting value from state

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below to your code

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {multiply: state.multiply.multiply, number: state.multiply.number}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in how you are mapping you state to props of your `Multiplier` component as written in combineReducer you have added **multiply** as the state name for your `multiplyReducer`, hence in your `mapStateToProps` function you need to can access your `multiplyReducer` state by the following code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {multiply: state.multiply.multiply, number: state.multiply.number}
};
```

Thanks I hope this helps.